# Why do the plot and patch commands both not execute in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

So I was tasked with plotting the Golden Rectangles along with the Golden Spiral over top of the rectangles. We were given the code for the rectangles, for the "spiral" I used multiple arcs from this [forum post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/278048), and I can only use `if` and `for` statements. The code for the rectangles works and the code for the spiral almost works, but what I really need is to get the `patch` to display behind the `plot`. This is the code that I have now:

```
clear variables; close all; clc

phi = (1+sqrt(5))/2;
x0 = 0;
y0 = 0;

for i = 1:8
    edgeLength = 1/(phi^(i-1));
    moveLength = 1/(phi^i);
    modStep = mod(i,4);
    if (modStep == 1) %move W, orient NW
       x0 = x0 - moveLength; 
       sx = [x0 x0 x0-edgeLength x0-edgeLength];
       sy = [y0 y0+edgeLength y0+edgeLength y0];

       %spiral
       P1 = [(x0-edgeLength);y0];
       P2 = [x0;(y0+edgeLength)];
       P0 = [x0;y0];
       n = 1000;
       v1 = P1-P0;
       v2 = P2-P0;
       c = det([v1,v2]);
       a = linspace(0,atan2(abs(c),dot(v1,v2)),n);
       v3 = [0,-c;c,0]*v1;
       v = v1*cos(a)+((norm(v1)/norm(v3))*v3)*sin(a);
       if i == 1
           vx1 = v(1,:);
           vy1 = v(2,:);   
       elseif i == 5
           vx6 = (v(1,:)+(1/(phi^5)));
           vy6 = (v(2,:)+(1/(phi^5))); 
       end
    end
    if (modStep == 2) %move N, orient NE
       y0 = y0 + moveLength;
       sx = [x0 x0+edgeLength x0+edgeLength x0];
       sy = [y0 y0 y0+edgeLength y0+edgeLength];

       %spiral
       P1 = [x0;(y0+edgeLength)];
       P2 = [(x0+edgeLength);y0];
       P0 = [x0;y0];
       n = 1000;
       v1 = P1-P0;
       v2 = P2-P0;
       c = det([v1,v2]);
       a = linspace(0,atan2(abs(c),dot(v1,v2)),n);
       v3 = [0,-c;c,0]*v1;
       v = v1*cos(a)+((norm(v1)/norm(v3))*v3)*sin(a);
       if i == 2
           vx2 = v(1,:);
           vy2 = (v(2,:)+(1/(phi^2)));   
       elseif i == 6
           vx5 = (v(1,:)+(1/(phi^5)));
           vy5 = (v(2,:)+(1/(phi^6))); 
       end
    end
    if (modStep == 3) %move E, orient SE
       x0 = x0 + moveLength;
       sx = [x0 x0 x0+edgeLength x0+edgeLength];
       sy = [y0 y0-edgeLength y0-edgeLength y0];

       %spiral
       P1 = [(x0+edgeLength);y0];
       P2 = [x0;(y0-edgeLength)];
       P0 = [x0;y0];
       n = 1000;
       v1 = P1-P0;
       v2 = P2-P0;
       c = det([v1,v2]);
       a = linspace(0,atan2(abs(c),dot(v1,v2)),n);
       v3 = [0,-c;c,0]*v1;
       v = v1*cos(a)+((norm(v1)/norm(v3))*v3)*sin(a);
       if i == 3
           vx3 = (v(1,:)+(1/(phi^3)));
           vy3 = (v(2,:)+(1/(phi^2)));   
       elseif i == 7
           vx7 = (v(1,:)+(1/(phi^7)));
           vy7 = (v(2,:)+(1/(phi^6))); 
       end
    end
    if (modStep == 0) %move S, orient SW
       y0 = y0 - moveLength;
       sx = [x0 x0-edgeLength x0-edgeLength x0];
       sy = [y0 y0 y0-edgeLength y0-edgeLength];

       %spiral
       P1 = [(x0-edgeLength);y0];
       P2 = [x0;(y0-edgeLength)];
       P0 = [x0;y0];
       n = 1000;
       v1 = P1-P0;
       v2 = P2-P0;
       c = det([v1,v2]);
       a = linspace(0,atan2(abs(c),dot(v1,v2)),n);
       v3 = [0,-c;c,0]*v1;
       v = v1*cos(a)+((norm(v1)/norm(v3))*v3)*sin(a);
       if i == 4
           vx4 = (v(1,:)+(1/(phi^3)));
           vy4 = (v(2,:)+(1/(phi^3)));   
       elseif i == 8
           vx8 = (v(1,:)+(1/(phi^7)));
           vy8 = (v(2,:)+(1/(phi^7))); 
       end
    end
end
patch(sx,sy,0.8+0.2*rand(1,3));
vx = [vx1 vx2 vx3 vx4 vx5 vx6 vx7 vx8];
vy = [vy1 vy2 vy3 vy4 vy5 vy6 vy7 vy8];
plot(vx,vy);
axis equal
```

In the code, the comments about North, West, etc. are in reference to the rectangles that are displayed and their orientation. The parts of the code that make up the spiral are likewise labeled.

So I really have two questions, however, the one that is most pressing is why will only the `plot(vx,vy)` command only work and not the `patch`? I tried looking at other examples of things but they seem to just type each command in in the order they want them to print and it does it.

The other issue I have it that when I do run this code the arcs work perfectly for `i = 1:4` but after that, you can see, the lines are all messed up. I don't really know why that is either.
If I left out any other information I'm sorry!
Thank you

Comment: This is a really long code, Its unlikely that someone will debug it for you

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I just need to get the `patch` and `plot` to work

Comment: They work, if they are showing bad things is because the data. And the data comes from your algorithm

Comment: When I run the code all it does is display the `plot` and not the `patch`. I'd put up a picture if I could.

Comment: If the current axes has the `NextPlot` property set to `replace`, `plot` will reset all of the properties of the axes before plotting its data.  Use either `hold('on')`/`hold('off')` or manually set the axes property to `add`.

Comment: Thanks, that gets both of them to show up now